# How can I calculate the total number of times an activity in android is displayed on screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Suppose i have a `SecondActivity` , I open the app and go to SecondActivity that should be `count = 1` time, now I navigate to ThirdActivity and go back to `SecondActivity` that should be now `count=2`. Next I minimize the app, and then open the app, the count should now be `count = 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static int in the Activity, initialized to 0.  In onResume, increment it.